# What can cause HTTP GET to localhost to timeout when the server thinks it responded?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Java application running in AWS Beanstalk (Tomcat 8.5 + Apache httpd).

At one point the app calls a REST endpoint on localhost.

Occasionally I see a failure such as this in the log:

```
14:55:45 ... SEVERE: url[http://localhost/detail.api?id=200030599] timing=12.010 ...
```

That indicates that my `CustomRestTemplate` gave up waiting for a response, after 12 seconds.

However, looking a few lines up in the log, I see a log entry from the service endpoint:

```
{
    "server_ts": "2020-08-19T14:55:33.890Z",
    "remote_ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "local_ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/detail.api",
    "query_string": "?id=200030599",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "http_status": 200,
    "referer": null,
    "user_agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_252)",
    "time_elapsed": 5,
    "thread_name": "http-nio-8080-exec-20",
    "host": "localhost",
}
```

That's my custom servlet logger showing a **5 millisecond** response. This is logged from the outer wrapping Servlet Filter.

This problem is recurring but rare enough that I can't reproduce it. So I need to take an intellectual approach... develop a series of hypothesis and a test to disprove each one until the correct one is found.

What are some possible causes?

*What have I tried so far*

I wrote custom loggers so I could capture the timings shown above. Then I basically hit a brick wall as the timeout happens in some hidden dimension between the response being sent by the "server" (localhost endpoint) and the response being read by the client.

I see that the Apache log (from elasticbeanstack) also shows the local request:

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [19/Aug/2020:14:55:33 +0000] "GET /detail.api?id=200030599 HTTP/1.1" 200 4982 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_252)"
```

Comment: Have you tried `GET /detail?id=####` ? Notice the .api not present in my suggestion.

Comment: check the "connection" header... a lot of times REST clients will not recognize a complete response unless the connection:close header is received. Postman will do that when testing endpoints... it will show a body response but the connection remains open and the response time just keeps ticking and may end up reaching some timeout limit on your client

Comment: @DynasticSponge I like your thinking, that would be consistent with the symptoms. I'll add wire-level logging to try to catch it the next time it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to reproduce the problem in a local test using JMeter.

Turns out the "hidden dimension" is lurking in a Servlet Filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    long started = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    
    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - started;
    
    log(request, response, elapsed);

}
```

The `log()` calls contains a synchronous database insert which slows down and eventually fails under load. I assume the servlet engine keeps the connection open until this filter returns. Investigation moves on to finding a fix now.